# Watching a mapped network drive with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, watch, sane

I'm trying to watch a mapped network drive with node.js using sane package. I'm in ubuntu.

I watch the mapped network drive and it only emits events if I make any change in the mounted dir but NOT if the change is made locally in the network drive.

Why is this happening? Has anything to do with permissions?

the code I'm using:

```
var path = require("path"),
    express = require("express"),
    sane = require('sane'),
    fs = require("fs");


var watcher = sane('/media/FTP/', {glob: '**/*.*'});

console.log(watcher);

watcher.on('change', function(filepath, root, stat) {
    console.log(filepath);    
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read [this](https://github.com/amasad/sane#how-to-choose-a-mode)?

Comment: Update: Tried in Windows and it's works. Though it seems sane doesn't like to watch a complete unit but directories working in Windows.

Comment: So which mode are you using on Linux?